Geometry Nodes Merge Proximity
I'm trying to create two 3D objects like this:

but with their edges merged like this:

using geometry nodes.
Can someone point me to some resources that will let me do this? I tried convex hull, it isn't what I wanted. I tried to fake it, but it doesn't look right.
I wanted it to be a bit tighter between the two objects like this:

I tried this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mA3YnlwbI10
but the result doesn't look good. I will try to play around with the parameters to see if I can get it to look like what I wanted.

You could do a GN tree like this. Put all the objects into a collection, then convert join that with the current object, remesh it and then add a smooth modifier after that.

Result:

You could also try using the metaball object type. Not exactly GN but it's also specifically designed for exactly the purpose you're talking about.


thank you so much, jakemoyo. it is exactly what I was attempting :)
